# Slow boot after changing some hardware components

Tags: boot, hardware, performance

I have problem with booting Ubuntu after changing the computer case and removing a network card and a PCI ATA controller.

Before that, it started in a few seconds:

```
Feb  1 09:02:20 mkskomp systemd[1]: Startup finished in 3.442s (kernel) + 11.089s (userspace) = 14.532s.
```

and now it takes almost 5x as long, over a minute:

```
Feb  5 21:55:19 mkskomp systemd[1]: Startup finished in 58.857s (kernel) + 12.129s (userspace) = 1min 10.986s.
```

In `syslog` I didn't find any problems. How and where I can find what's wrong?

**System version:**

```
mks@mkskomp:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

**Info:**

```
mks@mkskomp:~$ systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20
          8.129s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.518s apt-daily.service
           849ms dev-sda2.device
           628ms ModemManager.service
           461ms nmbd.service
           431ms accounts-daemon.service
           421ms samba-ad-dc.service
           368ms gpu-manager.service
           368ms grub-common.service
           344ms networking.service
           326ms timidity.service
           310ms thermald.service
           299ms apport.service
           279ms speech-dispatcher.service
           271ms ondemand.service
           240ms pppd-dns.service
           238ms rsyslog.service
           235ms systemd-user-sessions.service
           213ms NetworkManager.service
           195ms avahi-daemon.service
```

I found command dmesg with shows what happen when the system starting.
What does it mean?

```
[    2.665226] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      GOODRAM          22.3 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.665499] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    2.665524] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 468862128 512-byte logical blocks: (240 GB/224 GiB)
[    2.665804] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    2.665807] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    2.665906] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    2.668204]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    2.668480] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.992139] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[    7.703694] ata2.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   11.175502] ata2.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   12.523436] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   17.719139] ata2.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   21.190947] ata2.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   22.538882] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   27.734583] ata2.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   56.237002] ata2.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   56.237009] ata2.00: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   56.237014] ata2.01: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   57.584931] ata2.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   57.740987] ata2.00: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[   57.740999] ata2.01: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 0)
[   57.782855] ata2.00: ATA-7: ST3250620AS, 3.AAC, max UDMA/133
[   57.782859] ata2.00: 488397168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
[   57.849488] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   57.849648] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3250620AS      C    PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   57.849887] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   57.849902] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/233 GiB)
[   57.850006] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use? And can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the second disc (SDB). When I changed SATA port the problem disappeared.

Feb 17 13:50:42 mkskomp systemd[1]: Startup finished in 4.111s (kernel) + 14.636s (userspace) = 18.748s.